# Nothing happens when selecting any "Actions" dropdown options

Tags: wordpress, search, actions

After upgrading to 5.12.1 (and then 5.12.3), none of the dropdown options under "Actions" work. For example, when conducting an Advanced Search and selecting, "Print/Merge Documents" or "Export Contacts," nothing happens.

Here is the console error:

```
main-menu.js?r=dBZqC:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at isQuickSearchOnGoing (main-menu.js?r=dBZqC:66)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main-menu.js?r=dBZqC:99)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:3)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.<computed> [as click] (jquery.min.js?r=dBZqC:4)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try Clear Caches (administer - system settings - Cleanup Caches)? Also try to empty the templates_c folder?

Comment: @Demerit Tried those already and again today--no luck!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was a conflict with the CiviCRM Bootstrap Theme. Disabling the extension resolved the problem.

Comment: Worked for me also to fix, but other extensions like Mosaic are dependent on the CiviCRM Bootstrap Theme extension.  Had to disable, used the 'action' and then re-enabled.

Comment: It's my understanding that the extension is only supported for Drupal, so if you're using Wordpress it should be safe to leave disabled.

Comment: Not what I observed in WordPress.  The Mosaic extension is dependent on it.

Comment: Have same problem with 5.13.5 and Drupal.   Need to restore Shoreditch - any suggestions on solution that does not required disabling shoreditch?

Comment: Solved problem by disabling Shoreditch (Bootstrap) extension, disabling CiviCRM css on Settings -  Resource URLs page, clearing caches and then reversing the above steps.     Most likely it was the disabling and re-enabling of Shoreditch/Bootstrap extension but cannot be certain.  Clearing caches alone did not fix the problem.

Comment: I have been having success doing the opposite--enabling after an upgrade and then disabling it to restore the Actions function.

Comment: On 5.21.1 and having the same problem.  Disabling and re-enabling following @DaveT process did not work.  Disabling Shoreditch and leaving it disabled did work, but breaks other things like Mosaico.  Currently stuck.